# How to test a WCF service with JMeter when the WCF method accepts parameter as an Stream Object

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance

There is a WCF service. The method I have to access has 1 parameter as input whose type is Stream.

I don't know how to provide stream object from JMeter to the WCF service.

Currently, I have written a C# method (MVC Project) which accepts string from JMeter and then converts it into Stream type object, Which is then processed by the WCF service. But this approach does not give the actual performance of the WCF service

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can send a Byte Array as parameter through HTTP Sampler.
HTTP Sampler only works with Strings.

So one of the solution is to use the Java Request Sampler. You can make you customized sampler and create a byte array and send it as parameter.